# Truncate Time Converting list to nullable

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

```
 public List<DateTime> CalorieDates(int patientId)
    {
        using (var db = new DbConn())
        {
            List<DateTime> query =
                db.Calories.Where(d => d.PatientId == patientId && d.FoodId != "initial" && d.DateOfEntry != null)
                    .Select(d => System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.TruncateTime(d.DateOfEntry)).Distinct().ToList();

            return query;
        }

    }
```

Why is this converting my list to nullable datetimes?

```
Error   CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 
'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.DateTime?>'
to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.DateTime>'
```

How do I prevent this? I do not want a list of nullable datetimes.

Comment: Presumably because that;s what `TruncateTime()` returns.

Comment: Insert `.Value` after `TruncateTime(d.DateOfEntry)`

Comment: @IvanStoev `GetValueOrDefault()` is preferable as it will will avoid null reference exceptions if any of the values are null

Comment: @stuartd If the passed argument is not a nullable type (which seems to be the case, since OP is expecting `DateTime`), then the result will not be nullable too, i.e. we are just eliminating the side effect of a poorly designed method. And frankly I prefer getting an exception than silently a "safe" unexpected value. Of course that's just a matter of personal preference.

Comment: @IvanStoev Inserting Value was the answer. You can post it as an answer and I'll except it.

Comment: @IvanStoev well, I guess there's a tradeoff, and I like to take the more defensive side. I also don't assume that values that are currently nullable but always not-null will always and forever be that way, having seen them swing both ways in non-trivial production systems: if at some point in the future the value was to become nullable, and this method wasn't run often enough to detect it, then you've got a production bug and someone somewhere is shouting. I don't want them to be shouting at me!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For some unknown reason (probably to make the query providers life easier), `DbFunctions` class does not provide separate `TruncateTime` overloads for `DateTime` and `DateTime?`, but single method with `DateTime?` argument which handles both cases. However, as a side effect it's changing the expression type to `DateTime?` even if the argument is `DateTime` (as it seems to be in your case).

So you need to correct that. Once you know that you are always passing `DateTime` (hense the result cannot be `null`), you can simply add `.Value` at the end of the `TruncateTime` call and the issue is solved.

```
.Select(d => System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.TruncateTime(d.DateOfEntry).Value)
```

Comment: For EF.Core, the namespace is `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbFunctions`

Answer (score 0):

```
.Select(d => System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.TruncateTime(d.DateOfEntry))
 .Distinct().ToList().Cast<List<DateTime>>()
```

Answer (score 0):

Like @stuartd says in comments, `TruncateTime` is probably returning `DateTime?`; your `Select` returns `IEnumerable<DateTime?>` because that's what your lambda gives it from `TruncateTime`, `Distinct()` returns the same, and `ToList()` converts it into `List<DateTime?>` because, hey that's what `IEnumerable<DateTime?>.ToList()` returns.

So you end up with a list of `DateTime?`. That's easy. If you don't want that, `Select` something else.

Now, I'm going to assume that `TruncateTime` returns a nullabe type because it may return null. My guess is that its parameter is `DateTime?`, and it'll only return null if you pass in a null. Since you're passing in a struct, it probably can't return null in your particular usage of it, but I don't know so I'll play it safe.

So you want to convert your enumeration of nullable datetimes to regular ones, without casting any null nullables to regular `DateTime`. So first filter down to the ones that aren't null, then select their values.

```
.Select(d => System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.TruncateTime(d.DateOfEntry))
    .Where(d => d.HasValue)
    .Select(d => d.Value)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like the db method you are calling to truncate the datetime simply [removes the time portion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions.truncatetime(v=vs.113).aspx)

If that is the case then use the following instead.

```
List<DateTime> query = db.Calories.Where(d => d.PatientId == patientId && d.FoodId != "initial" && d.DateOfEntry != null)
                .Select(d => d.DateOfEntry.Date).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: That was the first thing I did, it doesn't work thats why I had to use Truncate.